# Need help creating a boundless array for Arduino (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, break

I'm trying to make an arduino copy of Simon Says, the kids game where you press the colors in the same succession they appeared before, with a Joy Stick for an independent study at school. I think what I have so far will, or would, work however the array I've made gives me the "error: storage size of 'setOrder' isn't known" which makes sense because I've declared it as "int setOrder[];", but this is exactly what I want. An array which has no variables when it is created but can add variables in as the game progresses... This is what I have in my code thus far, please tell me how it looks, and how I can make an array like this. Thank You!!

```
int xAxis = A0;
int yAxis = A1;
int push = 6;

int blue = 9;
int yellow = 10;
int green = 11;
int red = 12;
int play = 0;
int setOrder[];      /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(push, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(push, HIGH); 
}

void loop()
{
 if(!digitalRead(push)){
   play = 1;
   Serial.println("start!");
 } 

 if(play = 1){
   for(int i = 0; i<=sizeof(setOrder); i++){
     setOrder[i] = random(1, 4);
     for(int j = 0; j<=sizeof(setOrder); j++){
       int k = setOrder[j];
       if(k=1){
       digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); delay(750); digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
       }
       if(k=2){
       digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH); delay(750); digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
       }
       if(k=3){
       digitalWrite(green, HIGH); delay(750); digitalWrite(green, LOW);
       }
       if(k=4){
       digitalWrite(red, HIGH); delay(750); digitalWrite(red, LOW);
       }
     }  

     int playback[sizeof(setOrder)];
     for(int l = 0; l<=sizeof(playback); l++){

       //player presses RIGHT green led
       if(analogRead(xAxis) > 600){
         playback[l] = 4;
           if(playback[l] == setOrder[l]){
             digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
           }
           else{
             digitalWrite(green, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH); digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
             play = 0;
             break;
           }
       }

       //player presses LEFT yellow led
       if(analogRead(xAxis) < 400){
         playback[l] = 2;
           if(playback[l] == setOrder[l]){
             digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
           }
           else{
             digitalWrite(green, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH); digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
             play = 0;
             break;
           }
       }

       //player presses DOWN blue led
       if(analogRead(yAxis) > 600){
         playback[l] = 1;
           if(playback[l] == setOrder[l]){
             digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
           }
           else{
             digitalWrite(green, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH); digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
             play = 0;
             break;
           }
       }

       //player presses UP red led
       if(analogRead(yAxis) < 400){
         playback[l] = 3;
           if(playback[l] == setOrder[l]){
             digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
           }
           else{
             digitalWrite(green, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH); digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
             play = 0;
             break;
           }
       }

     }

   }

 }

}
```

Also I'm not sure if I'm using the "break();" method correctly, if someone could tell me that'd be great! thanks again.

Comment: have you considered c++'s [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? You'll need a separate code block to add new items to setOrder.

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with c++'s std::vector, and not sure if it is supported in arduino... All I know is Arduino is made using c and c++ and some of their methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you look into std::vector.

On the first line after you check `if (play = 1)` your main play area, you run a for loop using `sizeof(setOrder)` without having put data into `setOrder` first. Even if this did compile, logically your code would always skip the loop. Once you figure out vectors (which I'm pretty sure is what you're looking for), you might want to change this to checking the size of your `setOrder` vector against a predefined maximum value (at which point the player wins?).

Here's a [tutorial on vectors I found from google](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33631-c-vector-tutorial/).

Also, a couple other possible mistakes/recommendations here:

- break your loop down into several sub-functions that you can call, so that reading your code isn't one giant block. This will also make it easier to find errors, as you can check that each function works, one function at a time.
- When you check `if (play = 1)`, you're actually using the assignment `=` operator, not a conditional check `==`. You're assigning the value of `1` to `play`, instead of checking to see if `play` is equal to `1`.
- You're using `sizeof(setOrder)` incorrectly. `sizeof(X)` returns the number of bytes `X` takes up, not necessarily the number of elements in `X`. If you use a vector, there's a vector.size() function that returns the number of elements in the vector
- Whem you check for the player's action, you call `analogRead(xAxis)` four times - once for each direction. The player's first input will always be checked in the first call. If it's false, the player will need to give another input to make it to the second if statement.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections, what should I do instead of sizeof(setOrder)? And I plan to also look into vectors, I know nothing about them so the video will be helpful.

Comment: That's a good point about the inputs... could I make a temp variable and set it equal to the player's action then just run the var though each of the if statements that way they wouldn't need to make multiple inputs for one move?

Comment: Yeah, that could work. I'm also not sure how you determine "when an input is finished" - what keeps the loop from reading a hundred (or thousand, or million) inputs as quickly as possible, causing the player to lose immediately?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean... The idea is that a random color (chosen by and stored as a number 1-4 in a vector) then the player will input a directional command which corresponds with a number and stores that in another vector. Then after each input it checks that position in the vector to make sure they're the same. If they are not then the player loses and the vector is made empty again.

Comment: This is more of a hardware-interface problem. I'm not familiar with the arduino, but it's possible that your code will continuously read in inputs, regardless of what the player is doing. in which case, the read-in inputs will most likely be wrong, and the player will almost always lose. 

Also, upvote and/or accept helpful answers.

Comment: A common problem beginners have with embedded systems is they act upon the current state of an input, rather than a change of state in the input.  For example, it usually isn't interesting to know whether a button is pressed, but it is interesting to see that a button is pressed now, but wasn't pressed last time I looked.  In your case, you will need to track the moment when the joystick moves to a location, and also when it is released back to centre.

Comment: Umm I believe that the joystick always reads the input as 512 along the yAxis and 502 along the xAxis so it is constantly taking in inputs I guess but they don't "do anything" unless they're greater then the vals I've set which are produced when you press the joystick in that direction, also I can't upvote because I don't have a high enough rep but I checked the check thingy on your answer and it turned green. You are and have been very helpful with this, thank you.

Comment: I would suggest creating a subroutine getPosition() which returns one of 5 values, centre, left, right, up, down and maybe "invalid" as well. Then you keep polling this routine waiting for the user to move the joystick to one position, or release it back to know when the next move is coming.

Comment: sjOh - I think I understand what you're saying and if so that makes a lot of sense I was just thinking that as I posted my last comment, but I have no idea how to go about that.

*ANSWERED* thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the direction detection, you might look at something like this:

```
enum Directions {
    Center,
    Left,
    Right,
    Up,
    Down
}

const int threshold = 100;

int getJoyStick() 
{
    // get the X,Y coordinates with 0,0 the centre
    int x = analogRead(xAxis) - 500;
    int y = analogRead(yAxis) - 500;

    /check if we are in the middle.  Both X and Y need to be small for this to happen
    if (abs(x) < threshold && abs(y) < threshold) return Center;

    //to detect up, down, left, right draw diagonals at 45 degrees from the centre
    //if we are more to the right than we are up or down, then it is Right.  This
    //is to cope if it isn't exactly horizonal or vertical
    //so y big might mean up, but if x is bigger, than it is actually to the right
    if (x>y) {
      if (x>-y) return Right; else return Down;
    }
    else {
      if (x>-y) return Up; else return Left;
    }
}
```

The enum is just to show the nice way of doing it.  You would just the same codes through all the code. But instead if it's simpler for you, you could just return numeric codes for each of the directions.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, I hate to have a lack of knowledge, but I have no idea what you've done here... Starting with "enum" and yeah pretty much all I understand in this is the if statement, but overall I am unclear what you are doing here. Sorry.

Comment: Nope I lied you lost me on the if statements too... Sorry! I'm learning still if you could explain that'd be great.

Comment: an `enum` is a type (like an int or char) that has a restricted set of possible values. Try [another random tutorial from google](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html). As for the `if`s.. what particularly don't you understand?

Comment: Okay thank you for trying to explain. I'll consult with my teacher in the morning and see if he can better help me understand because I'm still fairly lost. Sorry I don't want to waste your time trying to completely teach me something. Thank you for your help/input, if you have anything further it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in c++ langage like the c++ tag in your post suggest so, use **std::vector** instead of array.

A vector is a list that can grow during program execution. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is a documentation about vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use plain old C arrays, the easiest path would be an array of static length, long enough to accept your biggest number of entries.  Then you keep a separate counter saying how much of the array you are using at the moment.

```
const int MAX_ORDER_LENGTH = 1024;
int setOrder[MAX_ORDER_LENGTH];
int setOrderSize = 0;  //the number of entries currently used
```

Then when you are adding entries, make sure that setOrderSize stays less than MAX_ORDER_LENGTH.

beware that sizeof(setOrder) doesn't give the number of entries in the array.  It is actually the number of bytes that structure takes up.

the break; commands will drop you out of the innermost for loop, but not the outer one.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give this a try.